# Unable to download the file from local server to android emulator

Tags: android, download

I am trying to download the data from the local server on my emulator but I am not getting getting the data. How can this task be completed

my downloading activity is

```
public class DownloadZipActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       UnzipManager.startUnzipping();//Downloader.getZipURL();
//        System.out.println("    file     "+file);  
    }
}
```

My Downloader.java is

```
public class Downloader {

    public static String getZipURL(){
        String result = "";
        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            String url = "http://www.example.com/webservice-demo/File name.zip";
            String thePath = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("     thePath    "+thePath);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(thePath);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

            int timeoutSocket = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("getZipURL", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
            return result;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("convertZipURL", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }       


}
```

And my UnZipManager.java class is

```
public class UnzipManager {

       private static String BASE_FOLDER;

       public static Context localContext;
       /*
       *You can use this flag to check whether Unzipping
       *thread is still running..
       */
       public static boolean isDownloadInProgress;
       /*
        * After unzipping using this flag ,you can check
        * whether any low memory exceptions
        * Occurred or not..and alert user accordingly..
        */
       public static boolean isLowOnMemory;

     public static void startUnzipping()
      {
             /*
             * MAKE SURE THAT localContext VARIABLE HAS BEEN
             * INITIALIZED BEFORE INVOKING THIS METHOD.
             *
             * ALSO MAKE SURE YOU HAVE SET "INTERNET" AND
             * "NETWORK ACCESS STATE" PERMISSIONS IN
             * APPLICATION'S MANIFEST FILE.
             *
             */
             Log.d("DEBUG","In startUnzipping()");
             //UnzipManager.BASE_FOLDER=UnzipManager.localContext.getFilesDir().getPath(); 
            /*
            *
            */
         // Log.d("DEBUG","BASE_FOLDER:"+UnzipManager.BASE_FOLDER);
           UnzipManager.isLowOnMemory=false;
           //Start unzipping in a thread..which is safer
           //way to do high cost processes..
           new UnzipThread().start();
    }

    private static class UnzipThread extends Thread{
             @Override
           public void run()
          {
                     UnzipManager.isDownloadInProgress=true;
                     Log.d("DEBUG","Unzipping----------------------------");
                 URLConnection urlConnection ;
                 try
                {
                      /************************************************
                      *
                      * IF you are unzipping a zipped file save under
                      * some URL in remote server
                      * **********************************************/
                    String url = "http://www.example.com/webservice-demo/Package name.zip";
                    String thePath = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
                     URL finalUrl =new URL(thePath
                           /* Url string where the zipped file is stored...*/);
                     urlConnection = finalUrl.openConnection();

                    //Get the size of the ( zipped file's) inputstream from server..
                         int contentLength=urlConnection.getContentLength();
                         Log.d("DEBUG", "urlConnection.getContentLength():"+contentLength);
                    /*****************************************************
                     *
                     * YOU CAN GET INPUT STREAM OF A ZIPPED FILE FROM
                     * ASSETS FOLDER AS WELL..,IN THAT CASE JUST PASS THAT
                     * INPUTSTEAM OVER HERE...MAKE SURE YOU
                     * HAVE SET STREAM CONTENT LENGTH OF THE SAME..
                     *
                     ******************************************************/
                     ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                     /*
                      * Iterate over all the files and folders
                      */
                     for (ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
                           zipEntry != null; zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry())
                          {
                              Log.d("DEBUG","Extracting: " + zipEntry.getName() + "...");

                             /*
                              * Extracted file will be saved with same
                              * file name that in zipped folder.
                              */
                                String innerFileName = BASE_FOLDER + File.separator + zipEntry.getName();
                                File innerFile = new File(innerFileName);
                                 /*
                                  * Checking for pre-existence of the file and
                                  * taking necessary actions
                                  */
                                if (innerFile.exists())
                                {
                                       Log.d("DEBUG","The Entry already exits!, so deleting..");
                                       innerFile.delete();
                                 }

                                /*
                                 * Checking for extracted entry for folder
                                 * type..and taking necessary actions
                                 */
                                if (zipEntry.isDirectory())
                                {
                                     Log.d("DEBUG","The Entry is a directory..");
                                     innerFile.mkdirs();
                                }
                                else
                               {
                                  Log.d("DEBUG","The Entry is a file..");
                                  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(innerFileName);
                                  final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

                                /*
                                * Get the buffered output stream..
                                * 
                                */
                                 BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream =
                                  new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream,BUFFER_SIZE);
                                         /*
                                         * Write into the file's buffered output stream ,..
                                         */
                                        int count = 0;
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                                        while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
                                        {
                                               bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                                        }
                                         /***********************************************
                                         * IF YOU WANT TO TRACK NO OF FILES DOWNLOADED,
                                         * HAVE A STATIC COUNTER VARIABLE, INITIALIZE IT
                                         * IN startUnzipping() before calling startUnZipping(),
                                         * AND INCREMENT THE COUNTER VARIABLE
                                         * OVER HERE..LATER YOU CAN USE VALUE OF
                                         * COUNTER VARIABLE TO CROSS VERIFY WHETHER ALL
                                         * ZIPPED FILES PROPERLY UNZIPPED AND SAVED OR NOT.
                                         *
                                        * ************************************************
                                        */
                                        /*
                                         * Handle closing of output streams..
                                         */
                                         bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                                         bufferedOutputStream.close();
                                  }
                                 /*
                                  * Finish the current zipEntry
                                  */
                                 zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                            }
                          /*
                          * Handle closing of input stream...
                          */
                           zipInputStream.close();
                             Log.d("DEBUG","--------------------------------");
                           Log.d("DEBUG","Unzipping completed..");
                     }
                     catch (IOException e)
                    {
                             Log.d("DEBUG","Exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
                            if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("No space left on device"))
                                  {
                                         UnzipManager.isLowOnMemory=true;
                           }
                           e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   UnzipManager.isDownloadInProgress=false;
            }
       };
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you specify in which file you write the downloaded content... your code looks like copy&pasted a lot...

Comment: Does it crash? If so logs. If it does not, you must identify the part where it does not work.

Comment: MalformedException:Protocol not found,I have provided correct URL

Answer (score 2):

you should change the url to :

```
  url = "http://localhost/example.com/webservice-demo/Package name.zip";
```

localhost = 10.0.2.2 is the localhost of your emulater 
I use this address ,and I don't specifie www ,although my folders are under www.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the internet permission in mainfest.xml file